# Query same model across multiple applications with Sequalize

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I'm trying to query the same model `Brand` across multiple applications with Sequalize.

Is defining models in every application the best way?
Do the definitions need to match perfectly?

Thank you

Defined model in both applications but some unwanted results came when in one application associations were defined while not in the other.

Application **A** `online_retailer.models.ts`

```
@Table({tableName:'online_retailers'})
export class OnlineRetailer extends Model {
  @Column
  name: string;

  @Column
  website:string;

  @Column
  domain:string;

  ...
}
```

How can I access `OnlineRetailer`in application **B** assuming they both have access to the same database? Better yet, how can I make the same associations considering `OnlineRetailer` is `hasMany` & `belongsToMany` `Brand`model.

Comment: I suppose you can move model definitions to a common package (git or npm) and use it in both applications because they use the same DB. Why do you need different associations if you have the same DB?

Comment: After doing some research, it is against best practices to have two applications accessing same models due to coupling concerns. I ended up moving all definitions under one roof.